# Can I use 3D transformations and still get sharp text?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I want to use the CSS properties `perspective` and `transform` for simple 3D transformations. But I still want to get the best visual quality for at least those elements on which the transformation only describes a zoom without any rotations or distortions.

To give an example, the following code describes four divs containing some text. I use 3D transformations to zoom in on them. I want all of them to be sharp, but, on my system, some are not ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWkCa.png)).

```css
#outer {
  perspective: 1000px;
  perspective-origin: top left;
}

#sharp_far {
  width: 845px;
  transform: translateZ(500px);
}

#blurry_far {
  width: 846px;
  transform: translateZ(500px);
}

#sharp_close {
  width: 361px;
  transform: translateZ(750px);
}

#blurry_close {
  width: 362px;
  transform: translateZ(750px);
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="sharp_far">
    Foo
  </div>
  <div id="blurry_far">
    Foo
  </div>
  <div id="sharp_close">
    Foo
  </div>
  <div id="blurry_close">
    Foo
  </div>
</div>
```

The example should demonstrate how the result depends on both, the transformation and the original width of an element. My Browser is Chrome version 89.0.4389.114, running on Windows 10. One CSS px unit maps to exactly one pixel on my screen. On other systems, the effect will likely be different. I also tried it in Firefox, where the quality seems to suffer as soon as you set `perspective` with any kind of transformation.

A potential solution would be not to set `perspective` and to use the `scale` transformation instead, as demonstrated in [this pull request](https://github.com/enso-org/ide/pull/1465) for the Enso IDE. But this is not really good enough for our use case since we might need real 3D transformations in some situations.

In addition to a solution, I would be interested to understand how exactly Chrome chooses the rendering method here.

Comment: Some browsers might render things differently due to hardware acceleration. On my mac, chrome renders the transformations sharply; Safari and Firefox don't. I doubt there's a way to influence this type of render behaviour using CSS.